# Why Does Python Importing work for one time and when you come back you find an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

I imported a module and the codes were working as expected.
After a break, I came back and found the importing was no longer working.
I jumped to other projects, after some time I came back to check the importing was working.
Now importing is no longer working again.

Just curious to know what's wrong with python or me.

Comment: It may be caused because of the IDE that you are using

Comment: sure? Am using VsCode

Comment: I encountered the same problem several times in Visual Studio while I was coding C++.

Comment: which editor do you prefer the most for python?

Comment: There is not a general answer for this and there is no way that anybody else can *guess* what happened on your computer in between the times that you tried to do the import, nor any way that anybody else can verify that you actually attempted to do the exact same things in order to import the module.

Comment: If you have a virtual environment set up for your project, it might be that sometimes you try to run your files outside the venv. Or you might be trying to run from the wrong directory, i.e should be running in `~/project/src`, but somehow runs in `~/project`, which is important if you're importing local self-made modules.

Comment: sure, I've not been using venv
I should try it out.
Thank you  @TõnisPiip